# getElementsbyTagName is not a function XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, angular, xmlhttprequest

I've a problem.

I'm calling a web service which gives me a XML response so I used XMLHttpRequest.
Now I want to access to one value stocked in one node.

Here is my code for that :

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                        console.log("response : " + xmlhttp.responseXML.getElementsbyTagName("return")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
                        ...
```

I'm sure that `return` node exists and it contains something, because my XML response has to look like this :

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soap:Body>
      <ns2:carreNombreResponse xmlns:ns2="http://mathsutility.test.com/">
         <return>16.0</return>
      </ns2:carreNombreResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But the issue is that when my program executes `console.log` line, it return an error as :

```
 TypeError: xml.getElementsbyTagName is not a function
    at XMLHttpRequest.xmlhttp.onreadystatechange...
```

I've to mentionned that I'm using Typescript and angular 2 (but normally it's not supposed to change basic js functions).

Any idea to solve the problem ?

Comment: `By` needs to be uppercase too.

Comment: Have you examined xmlhttp.responseXML? If the headers are not set correctly on the request then this will be null.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Oh my god it was that. I'm a bit tired :) thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Hi Calliste it is happening because xml is not a DOMElement.
it is just a xml data type

I de recommend you to use xml parse functions instead of use DOM Functions

Jquery has a very good one to do this job

it is called

PaseXML
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Comment: Okay thanks for your response. I will have a look of jquery and let you know if it works. However, I don't know if it's recommended to use jquery in angular?

Comment: You should be able to get a a DOM Object from xmlhttp. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML

Comment: it is mate, actually, even though there is also a small jquery inside angular engine, most of the real world app, uses little jquery-based snippets and library.
and the most beautyfull part is, this does not conflict with the angular built in jquery, and with no extra conf required.